# Warning: Illegal offset type while create dyamic menu

Tags: php, mysql

I' am trying my best to create dynamic menu and submenu. While trying I got plenty errors, Was able to solve some errors.

**This is the current errror message am getting**

```
Warning: Illegal offset type in D:\xampp\htdocs\projects\xxxx.php on line 40
array(0) { }
```

**This function loops an array and created UL LI Dynamically & Levels**

```
function loop_section($array = array(), $section_parent_id = 0)
{
    var_dump($array );
    if (!empty($array[$section_parent_id])) {
        echo '<ul>';
        foreach ($array as $values) {
        echo '<li>';
        echo $values->section_name;
        echo $values->section_id;
        loop_section($array, $values->section_id);
        echo '</li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    }
}
```

**This function Query the database and gets the results**

```
function fetch_sections()
{
    global $db;
    $array = array();
    $query = $db->SELECT("SELECT * FROM sections");
    $rows = $db->ROWS(); // Returns an error
    $array[$rows];
    loop_section($array);
}
```

**Database Strucutre**
[This is the database structure](http://s15.postimg.org/916a7b21n/sections.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
$array[$rows];
```

Should be:

```
$array[] = $rows;
```

Since `$rows` is also an array, it cannot be the key in an array. Also the line `$array[$rows];` would do nothing, even if `$rows` was a valid variable to be an array key (int, string)